# Is Display.getDisplay(this) supposed to display something?

Tags: java, midlet

I am learing to display in Mobile Java application. I came across this example to start with, but it doesn't display anything. I am trying to understand what `Display.getDisplay(this)` is doing in this code?

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;


public class Midlet extends MIDlet {

    private Display display = null;
    public void startApp() {
        if(display==null)
            display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set some displayable to current display like

```
  Form form = new Form("Hello World");
  String msg = "Hello World!!!!!!!";
  form.append(msg);
  display = Display.getDisplay(this);
  display.setCurrent(form);
```

Comment: Thanks it is displaying now. Can you please explain why we have put display.setCurrent(form); line after the display and what this statement doing? Aren't we displaying first.

Comment: we are just taking the reference of display, we need something to set which is displayable (you are also welcome to mark it as accepted since it is :) )